# why does minified jQuery have line breaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I was including the minified version of [jQuery 1.9.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) on my site and noticed that the javascript code has 2 line breaks. Is there a reason for the line breaks? I thought minifiers are supposed to remove these. It looks to still work if I remove them, but I am unsure if there is any risks in doing so.

Comment: No idea if this is their reasoning, but some IDEs won't read lines that long. I've intentionally broken down minified code before so that I could search it with an IDE.

Comment: It also had this desc for --max-line_len _`--max-line-len` (default 32K characters) — add a newline after around 32K characters. **I’ve seen both FF and Chrome croak when all the code was on a single line of around 670K.** Pass –max-line-len 0 to disable this safety feature._

Comment: @B3aT thanks. not sure why that didn't show up in the related question. guess it is because of wording newline vs line breaks.